# How to save video from android Camera to OutputStream

Tags: android, camera, android-ndk, android-camera, mp4

I'm writing program that allows user easily access to their cloud storages. 
And now works on feature named: Cloud camera. 
We have activity that contain SurfaceView and two buttons: start and stop recording. When we press start button Android camera must start recording and write video to cloud file directly. For every cloud i made class that inheritance my Interface with method that provides OutputStream to file on the cloud.

```
private OutputStream getDropboxFileOutputStream(String absolutePath);
private RandomAccessFile getDropboxRandomAccessFile(String absolutePath);
```

I'm tried to create pipe via ParcelFileDesciptor, but using this way i lose moov header part(just nulls without info).
Maybe somebody knows any method how to do it?
As i know MediaRecorder provide method `mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(FileDescriptor fd);`, where we can use FileDescriptor as place where we want to save file, but i didn't know how to create FileDescriptor from custom OutputStream that save data to cloud.

Is there any way to create a file descriptor from self-made OutputStream and give it to camera?
Or maybe some other tricks that helps to write video from camera to Custom Output Stream without losing moov headers?

Comment: `MediaRecorder` cannot support most video formats with a stream, because it needs to go back to the beginning to update some metadata. I would record to a file, then worry about getting the file up to the cloud.

Comment: Then the application loses meaning. Camera updates moov header that locates in file start, but maybe there is any way how to catch header updates and update it on cloud file